# How to correctly invoke toString

Tags: java, tostring

I'm trying to create a `toString` method in a Box class to call in a BoxTest class. I've set up the methods I want to call (`getLength`, `getHeight`, `getWidth`, `calculateArea`, `calculateVolume`), which work fine by themselves, but I'm unsure how to use them when calling `toString`.

Here is a pastebin (http://pastebin.com/Ex520ST6) of my current code.

#### Box

```
public class Box
{
    private double length = 1.0;
    private double width = 1.0;
    private double height = 1.0;

    public Box(double length, double width, double height) // constructor with thrown exceptions
    {
        if (length <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be higher than 0");

        if (width <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be higher than 0");

        if (height <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be higher than 0");

        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setLength(double length)
    {
        if (length <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be higher than 0");

        this.length = length;
        System.out.println("The new length is: " + length);

    }
    public double getLength()
    {
        System.out.println("The length is: " + length);
        return length;
    }
    public void setWidth(double width)
    {
        if (width <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be higher than 0");

        this.width = width;
        System.out.println("The new width is: " + width);
    }
    public double getWidth()
    {
        System.out.println("The width is: " + width);
        return width;
    }
    public void setHeight(double height)
    {
        if (height <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be higher than 0");

        this.height = height;
        System.out.println("The new height is: " + height);
    }
    public double getHeight()
    {
        System.out.println("The height is: " + height);
        return height;
    }
    public double calculateArea()
    {
        double area = (double) (2*length*width + 2*length*height + 2*width*height);
        System.out.println("The area is: " + area);
        return area;
    }
    public double calculateVolume()
    {
        double volume = (double) length*width*height;
        System.out.println("The volume is: " + volume);
        return volume;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("The length is %f, the width is %f, the height is %f, the area is %f, the volume is %f,");
    }
}
```

#### BoxTest

```
public class BoxTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Box[] boxes = new Box[4];

        boxes[0] = new Box(1.0,2.0,3.0);
        boxes[1] = new Box(4.0,5.0,6.0);
        boxes[2] = new Box(1.0,7.0,8.0);
        boxes[3] = new Box(1.0,9.0,9.0);

        for (Box theBoxes : boxes)
        {

            System.out.printf(theBoxes.getLength(),theBoxes.getWidth(),theBoxes.getHeight(),theBoxes.calculateArea(),theBoxes.calculateVolume().toString());

        }

        boxes[3].setLength(11.0); // debug
    }
}
```

1. Am I on the right track, generally
2. Should I be using `"%s"` specifier in the `toString` heading
3. Do I still need a format specifier in the `printf`, and if so, should it be `%s` or `%f`, as my methods are type `double`.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code in your question.  Do not link to an external site.  If that external URL ever becomes invalid, your question will have no value to future readers.

Comment: I generally use a StringBuilder for my toString() method. You could still do your format() here after you've built up your format string using the StringBuilder(). But what you have here is largely fine. You'll have to post your code here though, rather than pastebin. May be better on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for the editing suggestions. I haven't posted much, so I wasn't aware there was  a suggestion for code input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toString()` override should return a `String` with the values themselves and not rely on external use of `System.out.printf()` (The method can of course be used within the class, but the class should return a fully formatted `String` and not one that contains formatters like `%s`). An example implementation is as follows.

```
class Animal {

    public String name;
    public int numlegs;
    public double weight;

    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Animal, name: %s, legs: %d, weight: %d", name, numLegs, weight);
    }

}
```

You would then retrieve the full `String` representation of the object simply by calling the `toString()` method.

It is encouraged to use `printf()` rather than large scale `String` concatenation as it makes for cleaner code (IMO at least).

Side-notes:

1. Your `toString()` method calls `printf()` but doesn't provide the values that should replace the formatters in the format `String`.
2. Calls to `printf()` should have the format `String` as the first argument and the values as the remaining arguments.